# Extract address from database and put the address into google maps with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, google-maps-api-3

Hello i'm new with c# and i've been asked to integrate google maps and connect it to database, anyone can help me?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36151/Show-Your-Data-on-Google-Map-using-C-and-JavaScrip

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation for Google maps apiv3?

Comment: do you have lat lan stored in datatbase ?or do you want to insert those ?

Comment: The question is too vague, please at least provide some code shows your attempt and be specific in what area you need help? Database access code? Loading asp.net page dynamically? etc.

Comment: in this problem i have stored address inside database not lat lan, i need to find a way to connect the database to google maps so i can put a pin in google maps after i get address from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing this on your initial post and your comment, and to be honest presuming that you know both C# and the maps API (and that therefore it's the integration that you need help with).

You will need to:

1: Set up your connection string.

2: Query the database for the address that you require.

3: Pass this address to the JavaScript that contains your map, personally I do this using a data reader to construct arrays from the information (if you need more than one address), and then pass them using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration
```

All inside an update panel.

4: Next you will need to extract the information from the arrays at the front end and then Geocode this using the Google Geocoding API to eventually get your plottable point.

Information on each of these steps can be easily Googled so I'm again presuming it was the combination that you were unsure about.

A couple of notes on the Geo-coding API though (presuming free licence):

1: You are limited to 2.5k requests per day.

2: The request limit is also limited, I have seen speculation that this is to around 5 a second (or 1 every 200ms) but from my experience it seems more like 2 per second.

As an aside the more information you provide the easier it is for people to help, and you will most probably be using SQL (with SQL Server) and not mySQL.

Hope some of this helps.